# Ubuntu server (apache) won't respond to external requests

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssh, server

I'm fairly new to this so I could be missing something totally obvious, but I can't connect to my server using my external IP.  Internally everything works like a dream (10.0.0.28/redmine), but when I try to connect using the external IP the requests time out.  I forwarded both my ssh port and port 80 as shown below, but that didn't solve the problem.
My ports now show as being open with www.portchecktool.com.

SSH works fine internally, but when I issue the command shown here it says connection closed by remote host.

```
ssh {my external ip} -pxxxx -i /home/millerir/.ssh/id_rsa -l imiller
```

Similarly when I navigate to {my ip}/redmine or {my ip} or {my_ip}:80 or my ddns service address I get connection reset while trying to connect errors from my browser.

I did check that the server was listening on port 80 and my ssh port as shown below.

```
me@ubuntu-server:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:xxxx            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      779/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:57384         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1192/redmine
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      862/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::xxxx                 :::*                    LISTEN      779/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      923/apache2
```

If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated.  I'm stuck and kind of clueless.

**redmine.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory /var/www/redmine>
                RailsBaseURI /redmine
                PassengerResolveSymLinksInDocumentRoot on
        </Directory> 
 </VirtualHost>
```

**http.conf**

```
<Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough reputation to post pictures yet :( but I did my best to include the text or my port forwarding setup.

Service Name  Type  Start Port  End Port  Server IPv4 Server IPv6  Active   

WebServer  TCP/UDP  80  80  10.0.0.28
   
ServerSSH  TCP/UDP  xx  xx  10.0.0.28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out after digging around that some routers don't like you going "out and back in".  I tried connecting to my server using data on my phone and it works now.

Comment: This is what's called address rebind protection.